# Odoo 14 Error when creating simple image with python image library PIL

Tags: python-imaging-library, odoo, odoo-14

I am building an odoo14 module. The model has an image which, if the user didn't select any I want to generate a red image and set it to that. this is my current approach:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if not vals.get('plan'):
        img = Image.new('RGB', (640, 480), '#FF0000')
        vals['plan'] = img
    res = super(Halle, self).create(vals)
    return res
```

the image property looks like this

```
plan = fields.Image(string="Plan")
```

unfortunately, I get the following error

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 316, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable
```

id be very thankful if you know a solution or workaround for this problem. thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a base64 string representation of the file content. You can check the [test_website_sale_image.py](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/website_sale/tests/test_website_sale_image.py#L50) file for examples.

Try the following code:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if not vals.get('plan'):
        f = io.BytesIO()
        Image.new('RGB', (640, 480), '#FF0000').save(f, 'JPEG')
        f.seek(0)
        vals['plan'] = base64.b64encode(f.read())
    res = super(SaleOrder, self).create(vals)
    return res
```